# Why isn't my scrolling function working correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Could someone please tell me why my code isn't working? I feel like I have tried everything to troubleshoot but I don't understand what the issue is.

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
function load_arrow {
 $('.fa.fa-caret-square-o-down').addClass('load');

};
$(window).scroll(function () {
 function get_window_position {
  var $window = $(window);
  var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
  var window_height = $window.height();
  var window_bottom = (window_top_position + window_height);
  var $element = $('.element');
  var element_top = $element.offset().top;
  var element_height = $element.height();
  var element_bottom = (element_top + element_height);
  if ((window_bottom > element_top) && (window_top_position < element_bottom)) {
   $('.element').addClass('load');
  };
  else {
   $('.element')removeClass('load');
  };
 };
});
});
```

Comment: You are defining `get_window_position` (without `()`, mind you, so that's an error that should definitely be in the console), but never calling it. So... yeah.

Comment: defining functions without () ?

Comment: -_____-    thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Your code is full of syntax errors. Open your console (F12), it must be yelling.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function load_arrow { // Should be function load_arrow() {
        $('.fa.fa-caret-square-o-down').addClass('load');

    };
    $(window).scroll(function () {
         // A function defined in a function and then never called...
        function get_window_position { // <---- Should be get_window_position() anyway.
            var $window = $(window);
            var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
            var window_height = $window.height();
            var window_bottom = (window_top_position + window_height);
            var $element = $('.element');
            var element_top = $element.offset().top;
            var element_height = $element.height();
            var element_bottom = (element_top + element_height);
            if ((window_bottom > element_top) && (window_top_position < element_bottom)) {
                $('.element').addClass('load');
            }; // <---------------  Syntax error, remove the ;
            else {
                $('.element')removeClass('load');
            };
        };
    });
});
```